# DB problem in android

Tags: android, database-connection

i am having a DB connection in my application.i used below code

```
 db = openOrCreateDatabase(
            "highscore.db"
            , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
            , null
            );

        db.setVersion(1);
        final String CREATE_TABLE_HIGHSCORE =
            "CREATE TABLE HIGHSCOREDETAILS ("
            + "NAME TEXT,"
            + "SCORE INTEGER);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_HIGHSCORE);
```

but when the second time i am running the app it crashes...the error showing is

```
 06-13 16:35:51.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1398): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table HIGHSCOREDETAILS already exists: CREATE TABLE HIGHSCOREDETAILS (NAME TEXT,SCORE INTEGER);
```

And i also want to retrieve the greatest value in the score column.This is the first time i am working with DB connection...so please help me...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HIGHSCOREDETAILS (
```

To get the highest value use this:

```
SELECT MAX(SCORE) FROM HIGHSCOREDETAILS
```

Comment: thank u so much..it is working..can u provide the selection code...i am realy new to this stuff...

Comment: Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(SCORE) FROM HIGHSCOREDETAILS");

Comment: i am retrieving data in another class...is der any need to open the DB

Comment: How can I know how you receive the data?? I gave you query, told how to execute. Do you want me to come and write for you?

Answer (score 0):

Exception tells you that table HIGHSCOREDETAILS  already exists. If you update DB, check if this table deleted previously